# Correct pattern for "instantiating the instance"

Tags: python, class, oop, conceptual

*Note: In this question I am using Python syntax and Python terminology, but I am asking for the **conceptual** approach, independent of actual programming language, to make sure that answers would be useful for broader audience.*

## Level 0

Let's start with few functions:

```
def dog_tell(name, target, what):
    print(f"{name} the dog tells {what} to {target}")

def dog_bark(name, target):
    print(f"{name} the dog says 'Bark at you, {target}'")

def dog_wag(name, target):
    print(f"{name} the dog wags tail at {target}")

def dog_woof(name):
    print(f"{name} the dog woofs")
```

To use these functions, first argument is expected to be the dog name, so it would do something useful like this:

```
>>> dog_bark("Jake", "Finn")
Jake the dog says 'Bark at you, Finn'
```

## Level 1

Now, if we are using these functions with the same dog a lot, it makes sense to group these functions together, and only provide the dog name once. There are at least two approaches to do that.

### OOP

OOP approach is to declare the Dog class and provide it with name:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def tell(self, target, what):
        print(f"{self.name} the dog tells {what} to {target}")

    def bark(self, target):
        print(f"{self.name} the dog says 'Bark at you, {target}'")

    def wag(self, target):
        print(f"{self.name} the dog wags tail at {target}")

    def woof(self):
        print(f"{self.name} the dog woofs")
```

```
>>> jake = Dog("Jake")
>>> jake.bark("Finn")
Jake the dog says 'Bark at you, Finn'
```

### Functional

An alternative approach would be [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```
name = "Jake"
jake_tell = lambda *args: dog_tell(name, *args)
jake_bark = lambda *args: dog_bark(name, *args)
jake_wag = lambda *args: dog_wag(name, *args)
jake_woof = lambda *args: dog_woof(name, *args)
```

```
>>> jake_bark("Finn")
Jake the dog says 'Bark at you, Finn'
```

Both approaches serve the same function — they essentially attach some repetitive information to all function invocations.

## Level 2

Now, we are getting to the point of my question. What if Jake talks to Finn very often, and I would like to make their conversation an entity of some sort? I can easily do that with functional approach:

```
target = "Finn"
jake_tell_finn = lambda *args: dog_tell(name, target, *args)
jake_bark_at_finn = lambda *args: dog_bark(name, target, *args)
jake_wag_at_finn = lambda *args: dog_wag(name, target, *args)
```

```
>> jake_bark_at_finn()
Jake the dog says 'Bark at you, Finn'
```

This made one more step as compared to the instantiation, and attached *more* information to function calls.

**But what would be the correct OOP approach for this scenario? What if I continue this chain of adding partial state information to the class methods, effectively "instantiating the instances", "instantiating the instanciated instances" and so on?**

To clarify the intent, I think of something like this:

```
>>> jake = Dog("Jake")
>>> jake_and_finn = jake.with_buddy("Finn")
>>> jake_and_finn.tell("dirty secrets")
Jake the dog tells dirty secrets to Finn
```

While I know how to implement this "as is", my concrete implementation lacks the scalability, abstractness and beauty. It hurts my feelings of beautiful, and I feel I lack the understanding of something important at the very basic theory behind this.

Comment: The fact that you have to redefine the curried functions for each target is not very scalable. Level 1, you've labelled OOP is the "correct OOP approach". Not all languages support proper classes like Python, though. You could also consider the more readable solution: `Dog("Jake").tell("dirty secrets").to("Finn")`

Comment: @cricket_007, using your alternative is definitely more readable in the context of Jake the Dog, but in reality I am obviously not writing the Adventure Time framework, and instead of these I have different things like webdrivers, selector parametric substitutions, element bindinds etc., all happening sequentially, using previous "stage" as the base, adding additional state per method. But this is boring, who would read about webdrivers?

Comment: Okay, so that example would look like `webdriver.withBrowser("chrome").setJavascriptEnabled(true).selectElement("a")`... Same idea. Fluent API is what it's called

Comment: @cricket_007, things are way much too complex. While I appreciate your suggestion of fluent API, in my case it's not what I am asking for. To give the concrete example, part of my code executes at the "class definition" time, when Python constructs the immutable tree hierarchy of all views, components, subcomponents etc. And then this hierarchy can be bound to the webdriver, which would enable accessing views. And then, views can be instantiated given parametric substitutions, and they go through their selectors and do binding of components to underlying elements. And it goes on and goes on.

Comment: @cricket_007, the final idea is that it would be impossible to just write things with in this "fluent API" way, because that would incur too much unnecessary internal knowledge on the framework user, while I prefer not to expose implementation details, and keep the outer interface extremely lean & clean.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you just said really has anything to do with the question you've written

Comment: @cricket_007, well, I ask for the conceptual solution of "currying" class instances in an OOP way, which already happens once when you turn metaclass into a class, and happens second time when you turn a class into an instance. I want to continue this chain potentially indefinitely, adding some new state with the limited scope to the part of the parent object.

Comment: Python is multi-paradigm. You can write in both functional and OOP styles. If you have an implementation that is scalable and elegant in one style, just use it, no?

Comment: In Python, since you can return function handles, you can do `jake_bark = Dog("Jake").bark`. There is no need for the lambdas. Therefore, you can combine the approaches

Comment: [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) isn't quite the same as partial application, which is what you wanted. [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) does that: `jake_tell = partial(dog_tell, "Jake")`. It would also work for your second level case by breaking out of the "OOP" pattern and accepting that the bound method is itself a callable object in Python.

Comment: I think OOP paradigm does not fit in this case. If you still want an OOP approach, then you can create a class which will implement currying. For example, it would accept initial arguments in `__init__` as *args, ad hoc arguments in `apply` also as *args and you do `obj = MyClass(Dog, 'Jake', Dog.tell, 'Finn'); obj.apply('dirty secrets')`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you are talking about an abstract question about `graph`.

`jake` and `finn` are two nodes in the graph, and their communication channel is the edge in this graph. So if we construct every "dog" and their communication channel as a big graph, we can use two class to describe these two instances.

One is `Dog` as node, and another is `Tell` as edge. We instantiate every dog as a `Dog`. `Dog` has a function receives one parameter to specify his buddy, and returns an instance of `Tell` as a directed edge(determined by your need, it can be undirected.)

Finally, we use the instance of `Tell` to communicate.

For example:

```
jake = Dog("jake")
finn = Dog("finn")
jake_and_finn_tell = jake.with_buddy(finn)
# jake_and_finn_tell is an instance of class Tell.
jake_and_finn_tell.tell("dirty secrets")
```

Comment: Your answer, unfortunately, does not solve the stated problem. `Finn` can be literally anything, it's not implied that I necessarily establish the "communication channel", and Finn was provided just as an example of possible use. Rather, I want to find the correct way to bind the class instance with additional state, forming "level 2 instance", or "instance of instance".

Comment: @toriningen I just take your example to explain. What I want to point out is that abstract relation can be also  instantiated into an instance. In your example is "communication channel", but it can be anything no matter what `Finn` is. A well-constructed relation just takes care about the `action` but not any other thing, so Finn, even Jake, absolutely can be anything. Don't you think this relation instance is very similar with your functional approach? Suppose `relation` contains `source` and `target`, they are equal to `name` and `target` in your functional approach.